# Cypher: ThisShouldNotHappenError: This execution plan should not exist

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What's wrong with the following query? [Neo4j 1.8.2, Embedded]

```
start merchant = node:merchants('id:10')
match (merchant)<-[:VALID_AT]-(offer)-[:TARGET_PINCODE]->(pincode)<-[:RESIDES_IN]-(customer) where (offer)-[:VALID_OFFER]->() and offer.endDate > 1
return count(offer)
```

Webadmin returns undefined

Java Exception:

> org.neo4j.helpers.ThisShouldNotHappenError: Developer: Andres claims
>   that: This execution plan should not exist.   at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.PathExpression$$anonfun$4.apply(PathExpression.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.PathExpression$$anonfun$4.apply(PathExpression.scala:46)
>     at
>   scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.exists(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:79)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.exists(List.scala:45)    at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.PathExpression.apply(PathExpression.scala:46)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.PathExpression.apply(PathExpression.scala:31)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.NonEmpty.isMatch(Predicate.scala:283)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.commands.And.isMatch(Predicate.scala:83)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.matching.FilteringIterable$FilteringIterator.spoolToNextInLine(FilteringIterable.scala:55)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.matching.FilteringIterable$FilteringIterator.(FilteringIterable.scala:34)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.matching.FilteringIterable.iterator(FilteringIterable.scala:72)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.matching.FilteringIterable.iterator(FilteringIterable.scala:27)
>     at
>   scala.collection.JavaConversions$IterableWrapperTrait$class.iterator(JavaConversions.scala:557)
>     at
>   scala.collection.JavaConversions$IterableWrapper.iterator(JavaConversions.scala:583)
>     at
>   scala.collection.JavaConversions$IterableWrapper.iterator(JavaConversions.scala:583)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalBranchWithState.expandRelationshipsWithoutChecks(TraversalBranchWithState.java:70)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraversalBranchImpl.expandRelationships(TraversalBranchImpl.java:104)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.StartNodeTraversalBranch.next(StartNodeTraversalBranch.java:47)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.AsOneStartBranch.next(AsOneStartBranch.java:100)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.PreorderDepthFirstSelector.next(PreorderDepthFirstSelector.java:52)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraverserIterator.fetchNextOrNull(TraverserIterator.java:65)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.TraverserIterator.fetchNextOrNull(TraverserIterator.java:34)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.helpers.collection.PrefetchingIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingIterator.java:55)
>     at
>   scala.collection.JavaConversions$JIteratorWrapper.hasNext(JavaConversions.scala:574)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$21.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$21.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$22.hasNext(Iterator.scala:388)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:660)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$22.foreach(Iterator.scala:382)    at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.EagerAggregationPipe.createResults(EagerAggregationPipe.scala:76)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ColumnFilterPipe.createResults(ColumnFilterPipe.scala:37)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl$$anonfun$6.apply(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:127)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl$$anonfun$6.apply(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:125)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanImpl.execute(ExecutionPlanImpl.scala:33)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:59)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:63)
>     at
>   org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:79)

**Note**: return offer instead of return count(offer) works

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more

Comment: 99% sure this was fixed in 1.9. :(

Comment: :-( Wes, I'm sure you'd have mentioned it but is there any sort of workaround? This is the smallest part of a larger query so counting the offers in code won't work  very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to Neo4j 1.9 RC1 and the problem no longer exists

Comment: Workaround on 1.8.2: move (offer)-[:VALID_OFFER]->()  into the match clause. 
start merchant = node:merchants('id:10')
match (merchant)<-[:VALID_AT]-(offer)-[:TARGET_PINCODE]->(pincode)<-[:RESIDES_IN]-(customer), (offer)-[:VALID_OFFER]->() WHERE offer.endDate > 1
return count(offer)